# Ejecutar cURL con autentificacion digest en java

Tags: java, http, post, curl

Tengo un comando *curl* de la siguiente forma:

```
curl -X POST 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx' --digest -u user:pass -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary $'{"from" : "xxxx", "msg" : "xxxxxx", "frag": null}'
```

Quiero ejecutarla en *Java* pero no sé cómo insertar la autentificación *digest*...
Alguna idea?

Comment: veo que es correcto como habilitas la autenticación digest, pero que error estas obteniendo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). No lo he usado pero viendo ejemplos se podría hacer algo así:

```
// el json a enviar
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("from", "xxxxx");
params.put("message", "xxxxx");
params.put("frag", "");

// configuración del Realm para la autenticación
Realm realm = new Realm.RealmBuilder()
               .setPrincipal(user)
               .setPassword(admin)
               .setUsePreemptiveAuth(true)
               .setScheme(AuthScheme.DIGEST)
               .build();

// establecemos el header
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

// enviamos la petición pasándole la url, la entidad, el mime type y el handler para ella.
client.post('http://xxxxx', entity, 'application/json', new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // hacer algo
        }
    })).setRealm(realm).execute();
```

La ventaja es que puedes hacer petición sin depender de cURL, solo agregas  la librería a tu proyecto y ya.

Comment: He puesto una alternativa multiplataforma a lo que hace con cURL. El por qué usar esa librería, es por la simple razón que para eso fue creada. Si no escribe 5 veces más como lo harías normalmente.

Comment: Disculpa, pero no puedo replicar a ese comentario totalmente sin sentido. Esto ya es acoso.

Answer (score 0):

Estas habilitando correctamente la autenticación digest, me parece que tu pregunta esta más orientada a como ejecutar la llamada:

Puedes realizarlo mediante `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`

```
String command = "curl -X POST 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx' --digest -u user:pass -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary $'{\"from\" : \"xxxx\", \"msg\" : \"xxxxxx\", \"frag\": null}'";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);             
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output.append(line + "\n"); 
}
```