# Ejecutar sentencia curl desde android

Tags: java, android, curl, android-volley

Quiero modificar una imagen, y para ello, estoy ejecutando con éxito desde la consola de Windows CMD la siguiente instrucción:

`curl --user on:on --form "imgupload_front=@http://almeriaactiva.es/laguarde/imagenes_laguarde/a.JPG" --form code=code --form imagefield=front --form user_id=id --form password=pass https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/product_image_upload.pl`

También he probado la ruta: Memoria interna\DCIM\Screenshots\a.jpg

Ahora necesito hacerlo desde una app android. ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar la sentencia desde android studio? He agregado permisos de Internet, almacenamiento interno y externo. También: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`.

Desearía poder hacerlo ejecutando la instrucción curl, o en su defecto con la librería Volley.

He seguido varios ejemplos, aunque sin éxito:

[Ejecutar cURL con autentificacion digest en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13808/ejecutar-curl-con-autentificacion-digest-en-java)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803286/run-curl-from-java-android

imgupload_front --> imagen que vamos a subir

code --> código del producto que vamos a cambiar su imagen

Comment: Para hacerlo desde una App Android tendrás que usar `Volley` o `Retrofit`

Comment: Lo importante siempre es mostrar que se muestra en el LogCat, o que error obtienes al tratar de realizar lo que mencionas.

Comment: Gracias por contestar a ambos. No puedo mostrar el LogCat, porque no sé cómo implementarlo. ¿Me podéis mostrar algún ejemplo?